# Display Tag Sorting Issue

Tags: java, displaytag

I am using `displaytag` for displaying a list and sorting.But having problem with sorting.
I have a property orderdate format of the date is `Thursday 31 Jan 2012 13:10`. So if I sort this column then it groups the date by days. So I created another property `sortOrderDate` format is `2012 01 31 13:10` and using it in `sortProperty` like below.

```
<display:column title="Order Date" property="orderDate" 
                    sortProperty="sortOrderDate"></display:column>
<display:column property="sortOrderDate" 
         class="hidden" headerClass="hidden" sortable="true"></display:column>
```

What I exactly want doing here display `orderdate` on UI and sort it on `sortOrderDate`.
Any suggestion?

Comment: Show us your code, and tell us the type of the date property.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, if the data is a date, you shouldn't store it as a String, but as a Date. Date instances will naturally be sorted in chronological order rather tan in lexicographical order.

So you should just have an `orderDate` property, of type Date. And to display it in your column, and sort chronologically, the code would simply be (assuming you're using the JSTL, and the ID of your display table is `order`):

```
<display:column title="Order Date" sortProperty="orderDate">
    <fmt:formatDate value="order.orderDate"/>
</display:column>
```

You can of course customize he format of the date using the `type`, `dateStyle`, `timeStyle` and `pattern` attributes of the `<fmt:formatDate>` tag. See http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fmt/formatDate.html.

Th same technique can be used to display the string and sort using another string property, but it's really bad design:

```
<display:column title="Order Date" sortProperty="sortOrderDate">
    ${order.orderDate}
</display:column>
```

Comment: Well I cannot do the first change because I need to modify database column that will create too much code changes.
And Second solution is not working.

Comment: The first solution worked for me. I think your data must be formatted correctly in order for this to work.